# How to read the tilde in logic?

Tags: logic

How do you read this? What i think it means is:
if and only if $ x_1, y_2 $ are different-than/not $x_2 , y_2 $ then is $$ (x_1)^2 + (y_1)^2 = (x_2)^2 +(y_2)^2 $$

but this makes no sense because to prove that it is an equivalence relation is then it must hold for all the values and i can easily think of a counterexample.

[image: this is an example]

Comment: I would say $(x_1, y_1)$ equivalent to $(x_2, y_2)$. This symbol exists in analysis.

Comment: The pair $(x_1,y_1)$ is *equivalent* to the pair $(x_2,y_2)$ **iff** ... See [equivalence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that this is a particular usage of a relation $\sim$ which is not universal or known to everyone, but relies on **a definition** that you provided in the picture.

Recall that $(x,y)=(a,b)$ is true if $x=a$ and $y=b$.

Similarly, $(x,y)\sim (a,b)$ is true whenever $x^2+y^2=a^2+b^2$.